# Rails development server, PDFKit and multithread

Tags: ruby, thin, pdfkit

I have a rails app that uses PDFKit to render pdf versions of webpages. I use Thin as a development server.

The problem is that when i'm in development mode. When I start my server with "bundle exec rails s" and I try to render any PDF the whole process gets deadlocked because when you render a PDF some extra resources like images and css are requested to the server and looks like there is a single thread.

How can I configure rails development server to run multiple worker threads?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The simplest solution I have found is [unicorn](http://unicorn.bogomips.org/).

```
gem install unicorn
```

Create a `unicorn.conf`:

```
worker_processes 3
```

And then to use it:

```
my_gem_tree/bin/unicorn_rails -c unicorn.conf
```

Comment: You can also do this with puma, which is the default web server in Rails 5.