# How to mock slow response time in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an app calling an API which can take quite a while to respond (upwards of 10 seconds at times). I have taken steps to make this non blocking and show loading icons, however when I run the site locally the response time is very fast so I can't test whether my loading ui is working. Is there a good way to mock this in Rails?

Answer (score 1):

Add `sleep` to your controller actions, something like

```
def show
  if Rails.env.development?
    #Makes the request pause 5 seconds
    sleep 5
  end
  ...
end
```

Comment: Yeah I was doing this. The problem is that it totally blocks the server, so other parts will need to come down but will be blocked as the thread is sleeping

Comment: @cmwright yeah, but that's exactly whats going to happen in production with the long response time, right?

Comment: Seems you have several ajax calls run simultaneously. The only way to test it I see is adding delay and using multi-threaded dev server, like unicorn http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10097101/rails-development-server-pdfkit-and-multithread